# HTML table last td to take remaining width

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with one TR and 2 TD's. I want the first TD to adjust width automatically depending on its content, and the second TD to use up the remainder of the width.

This is what I have:

```html
<table style="width: 100%;">
  <tr>
    <td>short content</td>
    <td>long content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The entire table width is 100% (as I want it), but I don't know how to adjust the TD widths to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can give the first `td` a small width, e.g. `1px`, with `white-space: nowrap;`

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
td:first-child {
  width: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>short content</td>
    <td>long content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or, give the last `td` a large width, e.g. `100%`.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
td:first-child {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
td:last-child {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>short content</td>
    <td>long content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `white-space: nowrap` on all cells except for the last one, and giving the last one 100% width, worked for me:

```css
    td:not(:last-child), th:not(:last-child) {
      white-space: nowrap;
    }

    td:last-child, th:last-child {
      width: 100%;
    }
```

This will make sure that text wrapping still works while still filling the table when space is available.